# How to restore database from a Mac OS X disk image?

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

So I did take the ship with brave Capitan, and the ship ran aground... My Mac OS 10.11 tried to upgrade to 10.11.1 and freeze my Macbook! There was no backup, Time Machine stop working, so I did a dmg disk image of all and did the manual installation of the OS. Now I'm installing all things needed, one by one (there is no migration from dmg disk image). I've just downloaded MAMP, and than occurs to me... how to recover the databases still stored in the dmg file?

Is it just copy and paste a file? Witch one? Any suggestions?

Comment: You should recover the `my.cnf` and entire datadir and then try to start it and check the error log. The datadir needs proper rights and ownership to allow mysql to start.

Comment: The my.cnf wasn't important, but I found a mysql "suspect" folder inside MAMP, so I did copy it to new working MAMP and the data show up in phpMyAdmin - is this enough?

Comment: Find and check the error log, it will tell you if mysql sees any problem, other than that it seems to be OK.